# How Can I remove a marker from a Here Maps

Tags: here-api

I created a marker in HERE Map as follows

```
searchMarker = new H.map.DomMarker({lat:lat, lng:lon});

map.addObject(searchMarker);


function removeMarker()
{


}
```

I called a function on button click for removing **searchMarker**. How can I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To remove an object from the map you can use the `removeObjects()` method as described in the [API Reference](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics_api/h-map.html#h-map__removeobjects)

> **removeObjects** (mapObjects) : {H.Map}
>
> This method removes an ***array*** of object or an object group from the
>   map.

Something like:

```
map.removeObjects(searchMarkers);
```

As @guival mentioned in comments, for removing a single object you can call `removeObject()` [method](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics_api/h-map.html#h-map__removeobject).

Comment: can you provide assistance here?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31401059/showing-a-content-div-on-hover-of-a-marker-in-here-maps

Comment: Actually, since the question is about removing a single marker, `removeObject()` would be more appropriate (notice it's singular). So it would be: `map.removeObject(searchMarker);`