# Showing a content Div on hover of a marker in HERE Maps

Tags: javascript, maps, here-api

I am new to here maps and need to show a div on marker hover. I have been able to put markers with icons but now need to show a div with some extra information. Does HERE maps API provide this functionality? 
Any doc URL or piece of code will be appreciated.
NOTE: I am using HERE maps JS API for web.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been able to find proper mouse over events for HERE map's markers which are **pointerenter** and **pointerleave** and sample code to use these events is:

```
// After Initializing map with your own credentials.
var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
      defaultLayers.normal.map,{
      center: {lat: LAT_VAL, lng: LNG_VAL},
      zoom: 12
    });

var domMarker = new H.map.DomMarker(coords, {
            icon: domIcon
          });
var bubble;
domMarker.addEventListener('pointerenter', function(evt) {
              bubble = new H.ui.InfoBubble({lat:"SOME_VALUE",lng:"SOME_VALUE"}, {
              content: "Your content come here"
            });
            ui.addBubble(bubble);
          }, false);
          domMarker.addEventListener('pointerleave', function(evt) {
            bubble.close();
          }, false);
map.addObject(domMarker);
```

Comment: Recently I've found out that also events as `mouseover` and `mouseout` are good.

Comment: @edoardoo Didn't use it. Can you share some documentation/code.

Comment: I've added an answer to better explain and document. Remember to check it if it's the correct answer.

Comment: I did use Tap event but its has some limitations for my scenario.

Comment: in the line ui.addBubble(bubble); "ui" is getting undefined!

Answer (score 3):

You can create a tooltip effect by adding various event listeners to the map to check if the mouse pointer is over an object.

```
(function (ctx) {
  // ensure CSS is injected
  var tooltipStyleNode = ctx.createElement('style'),
    css = '#nm_tooltip{' +
      ' color:white;' +
      ' background:black;' +
      ' border: 1px solid grey;' +
      ' padding-left: 1em; ' +
      ' padding-right: 1em; ' +
      ' display: none;  ' +
      ' min-width: 120px;  ' +
      '}';

  tooltipStyleNode.type = 'text/css';
  if (tooltipStyleNode.styleSheet) { // IE
    tooltipStyleNode.styleSheet.cssText = css;
  } else {
    tooltipStyleNode.appendChild(ctx.createTextNode(css));
  }
  if (ctx.body) {
    ctx.body.appendChild(tooltipStyleNode);
  } else if (ctx.addEventListener) {
    ctx.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',  function () {
      ctx.body.appendChild(tooltipStyleNode);
    }, false);
  } else {
    ctx.attachEvent('DOMContentLoaded',  function () {
      ctx.body.appendChild(tooltipStyleNode);
    });
  }
})(document);


Object.defineProperty(Tooltip.prototype, 'visible', {
  get: function() {
    return this._visible;
  },
  set: function(visible) {
    this._visible = visible;
    this.tooltip.style.display = visible ? 'block' : 'none';
  }
});


function Tooltip(map) {
  var that = this;
  that.map = map;
  that.tooltip  = document.createElement('div');
  that.tooltip.id = 'nm_tooltip';
  that.tooltip.style.position = 'absolute';
  obj = null,
  showTooltip = function () {
    var point = that.map.geoToScreen(obj.getPosition()),
      left = point.x - (that.tooltip.offsetWidth / 2),
      top = point.y + 1; // Slight offset to avoid flicker.
    that.tooltip.style.left = left + 'px';
    that.tooltip.style.top = top + 'px';
    that.visible = true;
    that.tooltip.innerHTML =  obj.title;
  };


  map.getElement().appendChild(that.tooltip);
  map.addEventListener('pointermove', function (evt) {
    obj = that.map.getObjectAt(evt.currentPointer.viewportX,
        evt.currentPointer.viewportY);
    if(obj && obj.title){
      showTooltip();
    } else {
      that.visible = false;
    }
  });

  map.addEventListener('tap', function (evt){
    that.tooltip.visible  = false;
  });
  map.addEventListener('drag', function (evt){
    if (that.visible) {
      showTooltip();
    }
  });
};
```

This is initialised by passing the `map` object as shown:

```
function addTooltipControlToMap(map) {
  tooltip = new Tooltip(map);
}
```

The code as written is looking for a `.title` attribute to be added to the map objects - this could be updated to use `.getData()` if preferred. Tooltips can be initialised as shown below, taking either text or html:

```
function addMarkersWithTooltips(map) {

    // Simple Marker with tooltip
  var brandenburgerTorMarker = new H.map.Marker(
    {lat:52.516237, lng: 13.35}),
    fernsehturmMarker = new H.map.Marker(
      {lat:52.520816, lng:13.409417});

  brandenburgerTorMarker.title = 'Brandenburger Tor';

  // Marker with HTML Tooltip
  fernsehturmMarker.title ='<div>' +
    '<h2>Tooltip with HTML content<\/h2>' +
    '<img width=\'120\' height=90 src=' +
    '\'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/' +
    '8/84/Berlin-fernsehturm.JPG\' ' +
    'alt=\'\'/><br/><b>Fernsehturm, Berlin<\/b>' +
    '<\/div>';

  // Add the markers onto the map
  map.addObjects([brandenburgerTorMarker, fernsehturmMarker]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the **api version** you are using, you may find what you are looking for inside the documentation pdf (or at least start from there). 
Supposing you need do make some **HTML styled marker**, you may need:

- DomMarker (instead of a Marker, because it allows you to use ->2)
- DomIcon (which can embed html)
  An example can be found here https://developer.here.com/apiexplorer-v2-sample-data/template-web-default/examples/map-with-dom-marker/index.html

Anyway, if you need to show informations about the marker, I would suggest to use *InfoBubbles*, which have been developed for this purpose. 
From the **3.0.5** docs:

```
// Create an info bubble object at a specific geographic location:
ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(self.map, defaultLayers);
var bubble = new H.ui.InfoBubble({ lng: 13.4, lat: 52.51 }, {
 content: '<b>Hello World!</b>'
 });

// Add info bubble to the UI:
ui.addBubble(bubble);
```

To show them, you should attach an event to the marker *tap* event:

```
marker.addEventListener('tap', function (evt) {

    //create and add the bubble

}
```

In any case, you can find the documentation of your api version here: https://developer.here.com/documentation/versions

Answer (score 1):

You do not have "hover" listener for marker,
but you can show infoBubble on click

http://heremaps.github.io/examples/explorer.html#infobubble-on-marker-click

If this doesn't work for you, you will have to use jquery and to bind "hover" on HTML marker element. (This is not very easy task)